# Is it good practice to use jquery load method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it a good practice to load jquery's load method to load html files instead of reading the file at server in a protected variable and then writing the string on the .aspx page at the server it self.

I have 2 doubt, it will need to add another call to load the page, and if I have multiple calls to the same html file, then will it load it multiple times from server or load it once and then next time load it from the cache.

and it will also expose the hierarchy at the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `load()` method sends regular HTTP requests.
The browser will respect the caching headers that your server sends and reuse earlier responses when appropriate.

> and it will also expose the hierarchy at the server?

Huh?
It's no different from any other HTTP request.

Comment: So, is it a good practice to use load or to read the file at server and write the content there it self, without depending upon jquery.

Comment: @LokeshLal: It's better to do this on the server, for search engines, performance, and non-JS clients.